# Utilizar correos Gmail sin opción de terceros

Tags: html, gmail, smtp, outlook

tengo una pregunta espero me puedan informar al respecto,

Tenemos un programa el cual usa

*smtp:smtp.gmail.com

*puerto:465

*Teniendo SSL y Auntentificacion las dos con TRUE

*Y Correo con su respectiva contraseña

Estos correos de Gmail solo puedo utilizarlos activando esta opción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como dice hay esta opción **Deja de funcionar el día 30 de mayo de 2022**

Quería saber si hay alguna otra forma de utilizar las cuentas de Gmail en el programa sin necesidad de esta función.

Gracias y espero puedan ayudarme e informare.

Comment: Revisa este link por si ahí encuentras la solución: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: Me funciono Gracias es en el apartado de Cómo crear y usar contraseñas de aplicaciones, solo que es necesario tener la verificación de dos pasos activada.

Comment: A lo mejor esto puede servir, checa esta liga, saludos: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1672544-using-gmail-after-may-30-2022?s_tid=srchtitle

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Desactivación de aplicaciones menos seguras de google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/539336/desactivaci%c3%b3n-de-aplicaciones-menos-seguras-de-google)