# Desactivación de aplicaciones menos seguras de google

Tags: impresora

Quería hacer una consulta acerca de la nueva seguridad que a implantado google en sus cuentas de correo.
Desde el 30 de mayo google a realizado este cambio en todas sus cuentas.
El problema me a venido que todos mis clientes que disponen de fotocopiadoras con el escaner configurado de manera que escaneaban por correo electrónico y tenian como cuenta remite una de google me están empezando a llamar todos diciendo que no les funciona el escaner.
Yo por ahora la única alternativa que he encontrado a sido crear una cuenta de outlook en cada uno de los que me a llamado y configurarla con esa otra cuenta de remitente.
Alguien que domine un poco en el tema sabe si hay algo que se pueda activar/desactivar en la cuenta de google para poder solucionar esto sin tener que hacer todo lo que ahora hago?
Esto es lo que pone en google:

Acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras
Para proteger tu cuenta, se bloquean las aplicaciones y los dispositivos que utilizan una tecnología de inicio de sesión menos segura. Para mantener tu cuenta protegida, Google desactivará automáticamente este ajuste si no se utiliza.

Este ajuste ya no está disponible. Más información
Para proteger tu cuenta, a partir del 30 de mayo del 2022, ​​Google dejará de admitir aplicaciones y dispositivos de terceros que te pidan que inicies sesión en tu cuenta de Google usando solo tu nombre de usuario y contraseña.

Answer (score 3):

La desactivación de aplicaciones menos seguras, evita que te puedas loguear directamente con tu usuario y contraseña, pero no impide que puedas generar una contraseña específica para tu aplicación. Ahora, en lugar de loguearte con tu contraseña de google, te loguearás con una contraseña que generes para tu aplicación específica.

Los pasos para generar una contraseña para tu aplicación son:

1. [Activa la verificación en 2 pasos](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) en tu cuenta de google. Este paso es obligatorio, ya que google solo te permite generar contraseñas para aplicaciones en cuentas que tengan activada la verificación de dos pasos.
2. Ve a *contraseña de aplicaciones* (https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) y [genera una contraseña](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=es) para tu aplicación.

[image]

3. Simplemente usa tu usuario de gmail (`tu_correo@gmail.com`) y la **contraseña generada** que copiaste (cómo la que se muestra en la imagen).

Con estos pasos, cualquier aplicación que antes usaba la configuración menos segura de google puede seguir funcionando, solo necesitas generar y configurar la **nueva contraseña**.

Si quieres un ejemplo en `python`, te adjunto [el link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/539487/186586) de otra respuesta en la que pruebo este nuevo método de configurar el correo en python. Si quieres un ejemplo con C# en `.NET 6`, acá te dejo [el link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72553362/8838721).

Comment: Muchas gracias lo probaré a ver

Comment: La respuesta de Jaime Menendez es correta.
ya lo probe y me funciono