# Envio automático de correos con python y smtp (actualización junio 2022)

Tags: python, gmail, smtp

Actualmente google ha retirado la opción de permitir el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras como se puede ver en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

había escrito el código tradicional para enviar correos de manera automática con python smtplib

```
#SMTP Connection For Sending Email
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #use gmail with port
session.starttls() #enable security
session.login(senders_email, sender_password) #login with mail_id and password
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(senders_email, receiver_email, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

Ahora la aplicación no puede iniciar sesión.

Es de gran ayuda que me pudieran ayudar a resolver este inconveniente, ya que no tengo idea de como modificar la aplicación o la configuración de la cuenta de google para que me permita iniciar sesión desde python.

Comment: Creo, no estoy seguro, pero creo que vas a tener que pasarte a un sistema más seguro, como la propia api de Google.

Comment: Este último cambio en la politica de seguridad de google, nos ha hecho doler la cabeza a muchos. Aún no encuentro la solución definitiva, inicialmente opté por cambiar mis aplicaciones para que el envío por SMTP lo haga desde otro correo (no gmail). Encuentro esta pregunta muy interesante!

Comment: Pero el cartel dice que se puede reactivar lo que se desactivo automaticamente... Aunque, si dicen que es inseguro, por algo lo dicen.. no?

Comment: @gbianchi dejaron la misma leyenda de siempre, sin embargo ya no permite google reactivarlo. Ese ajuste ya no está disponible

Comment: Como dice la respuesta de abajo, debes garantizar una segunda verificación para evitar que te roben la cuenta permanentemente sabiendo tu clave (con la segunda verificación la recuperarías). Lo segundo es que tanto google como hotmail ofrecen crear una "clave de aplicación" que es una clave alternativa solo para la aplicación externa que registres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La solución es simple y no requiere mucho cambio.

1. [Activa la verificación en 2 pasos](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) en tu cuenta de google. Este paso es **obligatorio**, ya que google solo permite generar contraseñas para aplicaciones en cuentas que tengan activada la verificación de dos pasos.
2. Ve a generar contraseña de aplicaciones (https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) y [genera una contraseña](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=es) para tu app.

[image]

3. Simplemente usa tu usuario de gmail (`tu_correo@gmail.com`) y la contraseña generada en tu aplicación de python.

He probado lo que te acabo de adjuntar con el siguiente script:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
mail_content = '''
Hola Stack Overflow en Español!!!
'''

sender_address = 'tu_correo@gmail.com'
sender_pass = 'contraseña_generada'
receiver_address = 'tu_correo@gmail.com'

message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python. It has an attachment.'   

message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.starttls()
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

Y funcionó sin problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Infinitas **Gracias!**

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!, Funcionó a la perfección