# Gmail no Permite PhpMailer ultima actualizacion

Tags: email, phpmailer, gmail

Revisando el log de envios de correos con phpmailer usuando una cuenta gmail, me muestra que la opcion de envio con phpmailer ( aplicaciones de terceros) ha sido borrada... por ende gmail ha quitado la opcion de seguridad de habilitar aplicaciones de terceros. por el momento no se como solucionar esto.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No se necesita usar firma en las preguntas. Tu usuario se asocia y se ve claramente en la pregunta. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Acá tienes la solución a tu problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/539495/186586